# is there a way to get a value from a different foreach?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do a drag and drop update for a field in laravel.

All the backend stuff works, the database updates if I hardcode the values but I need to pull 2 variables through in the javascript.

I'm loading jquery 3.3.1 earlier in the script.

I'm having an issue with the userId when posting the data. It either always uses the last ID in the list or if I user the variable userIds it passes an array.

```
<style href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
      @foreach($users as $user)
      $("#draggable-{{$user->id}}").val({{$user->id}}).draggable({
         refreshPositions: true,
         snap: true,
         revert: true,
      });
      @endforeach
      var userIds = {{$userID}};
      userIds.forEach(function(element) {
         if(element === {{$user->id}}) {
            var userId = {{$user->id}};
         }
      });
      @foreach($funders as $funder)
      $("#droppable-{{$funder->funder}}").droppable({
         activeClass: "active",
         hoverClass:  "hover",
         drop: function (event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
               headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
               type: "POST",
               url: '{{route('update-funders')}}',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {'funder':$("#droppable-{{$funder->funder}}").attr('data'), 'id': userId },
            }).done(function( data ) {
               // console.log(data);
               // var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            });
         }
      });
      @endforeach
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the logic is trying to achieve? Whats $userID, IS THE $user is the `Auth::user()` and $users is a collection of all users?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#droppable-{{$funder->funder}}").droppable({
            activeClass: "active",
            hoverClass:  "hover",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                let userId = ui.draggable.attr('data-id');
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{{route('update-funders')}}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {'funder':$("#droppable-{{$funder->funder}}").attr('data'), 'id': userId },
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    // var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                });
            }
        });
```